# Owned type property not persisting for a modified entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to achieve something in EF Core that worked very well for me in EF 6.

I'm serializing the contents of a `List<T>` property as a Json string in the DB. `<T>` can be pretty much anything, since Json.Net takes care of serializing whatever we throw at it. My collection exposes a `Json` string property and takes care of serializing/deserializing itself.

This approach is convenient and efficient for structured nested data where a relational model would bring needless overhead and complexity.

In EF 6 I would do something like this:

```
[ComplexType]
public class SelfSerializingCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    protected string Json
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this); }
        private set
        {
            Clear();

            if (value == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(value));
        }
    }
}
```

EF 6 doesn't support mapping generic types, so we'd provide a concrete implementation for each type of List we might want:

```
public class PhoneNumberCollection : SelfSerializingCollection<PhoneNumber> { }
```

And then use it like this:

```
public class Contact {
    public PhoneNumberCollection PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

And that was it. Now, I'm trying to achieve the same in EF Core 2.0.

Here's what I have so far. The `SelfSerializingCollection<T>` class is unchanged.

```
public class Contact {
    // EF Core supports generic types so we don't need a concrete implementation
    // for each collection type.
    public SelfSerializingCollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // EF Core does not support the [ComplexType] attribute
        // but we now have .OwnsOne() in EF Core 2
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().OwnsOne(p => p.PhoneNumbers);
    }
}
```

So far so good. EF Core maps the `PhoneNumbers_Json` column in the DB. Reading and creating new entries works just fine.

But, unlike in EF 6, any changes to the `PhoneNumbers` collection on an existing entity are **not** being persisted back to the database. I am updating in a typical PUT method with `_context.Entry(contactModelFromRequestBody).State = EntityState.Modified;` - same as before. But for some reason, EF Core is not persisting my `Json` string property back to the DB for a `Modified` entity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EF Core treats owned types like entity types w/o own identity, hence properties that point to owned type are treated as navigation properties. And setting the parent entity state to `Modified` does not cascade to navigation properties.

However the `Update` method of `DbContext` or `DbSet` does cascade, so instead of

```
_context.Entry(contactModelFromRequestBody).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

you should use

```
_context.Update(contactModelFromRequestBody);
```

Comment: Much nicer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It seems necessary to manually set the modified entity state for my owned types:

```
_context.Entry(contact).Reference(p => p.PhoneNumbers)
    .TargetEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This does the trick, although I'm still hoping to find a more general solution that doesn't require me to mark all the owned properties like this on every update.

Comment: This is superior to the accepted answer. Did you ever find a more general solution to target a single property?